# c# How to acces an in from another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game and currently working on melee damage. I have done all the code for finding an enemy to hit etc but now I need to make that enemy take damage. That's why I need to access in the script for my enemys (Slime) curHealth int.

Here is the code for the melee weapon: (might be some swedish words dont mind about it)

```
{ 
    private float meeleAttackStart = 0f;
    private float meeleAttackCooldown = 0.5f;
    public int meeleDamage = 40;

    // Use this for initialization 
    void Start() 
    { 

    } 

    // Update is called once per frame 
    void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0) && Time.time > meeleAttackStart + meeleAttackCooldown )
        {
            RaycastHit2D[] hitArea = Physics2D.BoxCastAll(transform.position, Vector2.one, 0, Vector2.up);
            if(hitArea != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < hitArea.Length; i = i+1)
                {
                    if(hitArea[i].collider.tag == "Enemy")
                    {
                        // do stuff
                    }

                }
            }

            meeleAttackStart = Time.time;
        }          
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is my code for my enemy (Still in progress)

```
{
    public int maxSlimeHealth = 40;
    public int curSlimeHealth = 40;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you have found the enemy to hit, it should be `instanceOfThatEnemy.curSlimeHealth;`
But you didn't show the part where you found it so I can't say for sure.

Comment: It would've been nice if you could show what you tried already, now you just have `// do stuff`. Take a look at [ask]. You should show some research effort. Have you looked at [the API of Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)? You can see it has a [`gameObject` variable](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html), have you tried using that in one way or another? Also, your question doesn't contain a real *question*, I don't even see a question mark anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Easy and bad solution would be to just use `hitArea[i].collider.gameObject.GetComponent<TYPE_OF_YOUR_COMPONENT>().curSlimeHealth;`
But if you want to do this in a bit more elegant way, I would suggest making an interface eg. `IMortal` or base class `CreatureBehaviour` and then just call methods of that interface/abstract class. In example it could be something like this :

```
public class CreatureBehaviour
    : MonoBehaviour
{
    int m_Health = 40;
    public int Health { get { return m_Health; } }

    // you can add defense attribute 
    int m_Defense;
    public int Defense { get { return m_Defense; } }

    public void DoDamage(double atkPower)
    {
        // calculate this creature defence agains attack power
        int damage = atkPower - this.Defense;
        m_Health -= damage;
        // check health and other stuff.
    }
}
```

Now creating your slime :

```
public class Slime
    : CreatureBehaviour
{

}
```

And you can use this in a similar way but instead of checking if your `hitArea[i].collider.tag` is `"Enemy"` or `"AnotherTag"` you can just check :

```
var creature = hitAread[i].collider.gameObject.GetComponent<CreatureBehaviour>();
if ( creature )
    creature.DoDamage(13.37D);
```